# What fittings are needed to replace saddle valve with 1/4" compression valve on 3/4" copper line?

Tags: plumbing, valve, solder, saddle-valve

I have a 3/4" copper line with with a saddle valve, and I want to do a solid once-only job with sweated fittings - so 3/4" line with a T off-take with a 1/4" ball valve with compression-fittings on one side.

Browsing hardware store in person or online I see a dizzying array of options. Would appreciate experienced & knowledgeable info on what exactly to buy. I've sweated pipes before, it's just the actual parts I need advice on.

No SharkBite, please.

Comment: Why no SharkBite? I did exactly like RMDman suggests years ago with a SharkBite valve and all's been dandy.

Comment: hi isherwood - my daughter will inherit the house and is really not the kind of person that can and will go into a crawlspace. I need something that will last 60 years. I'm not well informed on plumbing as you can tell, so am unaware if sharkbite has that kind of lifespan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need:

- a 3/4" tee and a short piece of 3/4 copper pipe.
- a reducer down to 1/2", or a 3/4 -1/2- 3/4  tee ( then no 3/4 pipe needed)
- a short piece of 1/2" copper pipe
- a one quarter turn 1/2" compression shutoff with  1/4" compression outlet

[image]

```
                            OR
```

Take a pic of what you have and take it to a hardware store, (not big box). Show an associate, tell them what you want to do, and they will get you what you want with a smile.